# How can I import css based on a Vue page without importing it on different pages? Just loop through a config file I make, see example below

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, webpack

config-page-css.js

```
    export default {
        [
            'page' : 'Home',
            'css' : '/css/custom.css'
        ],
        [
            'page' : 'About',
            'css' : '/css/custom.css'
        ],
        [
            'page' : 'contact',
            'css' : 'css/contact.css'
        ]
    }
```

On app or main js, after the const app = Vue.createApp({}), There should be aloop to perform import

```
    import configPageCss from './config-page-css.js'

    const app = Vue.createApp({})

    app.mount('#app')
```

Comment: neither `App` nor `main.js` has the concept of which "page" (is this an SPA?) you are on, so it makes no sense to do that in either of those files?

Comment: @JaromandaX yes, It's spa. Is it possible using webpack though? Only import a css file based based on the given file?

Comment: you can import css in "the given file" - i.e. in your Home.vue (again, assumption being made) you could `import "/css/custom.css"` for example - though, if you're using SFC's you'd put the css in the .vue file - so, perhaps I have no idea of your code layout

Comment: @JaromandaX Thank you for this. This is what I did and experimenting if I could automate it rather than importing it manually on different .vue files.